# Search e-mail messages in given period of day or in given period of week

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Is there any way in Gmail's filtering mechanism to find e-mail messages received or sent:

- in a given period of a day (each day -- only time component of date matters here),
- in a given period of week (each week).

I need to list (among 26k e-mails) all messages sent or received during nights or weekends.

Any solution suits me:

- Gmail: temporal filter -- list all matching e-mails in main view,
- Gmail: permanent filter -- add specific label to all matching e-mails,
- non-Gmail: any external tool or solution that can help me achieve above.

If this is possible in Gmail then how should I configure filtering parameters? If this is not possible then is there any tool or solution I should look after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform searching between two time periods of a day like this:

```
after:1552896000 before:1552924800
```

which will list all emails you received between **8:00-16:00** on **18. March 2019** 
(timestamps were acquired by using **https://www.epochconverter.com/**)

However, in your case, you will probably need to apply the time interval logic on the far greater time range than a 1 day for which you can try to import all your messages from your Gmail inbox into Google Sheets and then filter out stuff you need by simple **`QUERY`** formula. There are various tools and scripts for this task all over the place.

An example would be **https://www.integromat.com/en** 

which comes with a handy tutorial: **https://youtu.be/9VNFoxR43II**

Answer (score 1):

Since (for some internal reasons) I couldn't use [the suggestion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126527/21486), i.e. to upload messages from Gmail to Google Sheets and try to filter them there, I came with [a semi-automatic, semi-manual way using Excel](http://onezeronull.com/2019/03/21/find-all-e-mails-sent-or-received-in-gmail-after-office-hours/), which is also inspired by [user0's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126527/21486).

To cut the long story short (details, discussion and alternative approaches are all [here](http://onezeronull.com/2019/03/21/find-all-e-mails-sent-or-received-in-gmail-after-office-hours/)) what I did was:

1. Fill tha **A** column with all the dates in desired range (1,5+ year, 610 dates / rows in my case).
2. Set a fixed start time and end time and store it in some separate cells (**C1** and **E1**).
3. Generate dates with given start and end time:

   - start date: `=DATE(YEAR(A4);MONTH(A4);DAY(A4))+TIME(HOUR($C$1);MINUTE($C$1);SECOND($C$1))`,
   - end date: `=DATE(YEAR(B4);MONTH(B4);DAY(B4))+TIME(HOUR($E$1);MINUTE($E$1);SECOND($E$1))`.
4. Convert these dates into Unix timestamp:

   - start date: `=(B4-DATE(1970;1;1))*86400`,
   - end date: `=(C4-DATE(1970;1;1))*86400`.
5. Concatenate resulting values to get filtering string and URL:

   - filtering string: `="after:" & D4 & " before:" & E4`,
   - URL: `="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/after%3A" & E4 & "+before%3A" & F4`.

And I have resulted with a long list of filtering strings and URLs, like:

- `after:1496419200 before:1496390400`,
- `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/after%3A1496350800+before%3A1496376000`,

ready to be pasted into Gmail's search box:

[image]

or into browser's address bar.

An example of the resulting sheet (get it [here](http://onezeronull.com/files/2019/03/Find-all-e-mails.xlsx)):

[image]

There are some more modifications to above to be considered that includes:

- adding extra day when hours are passing midnight:

  - change the `DAY(B4)` part
  - into `DAY(B4+IF($E$1<$C$1;1;0))`.
- using whole day (00:00:00-23:59:00) when day is during weekend:

  - first change:

    - part: `+TIME(HOUR($D$1);MINUTE($D$1);SECOND($D$1))`,
    - with: `+IF(WEEKDAY(A4;2)>5;TIME(HOUR($D$1);MINUTE($D$1);SECOND($D$1));TIME(0;0;0))`,
    - to ignore fixed start time and "reset" start hour to midnight (00:00:00) during weekends.
  - second change:

    - part: `DAY(C4+IF($E$1<$C$1;1;0))`
    - with: `DAY(C4+IF(AND($F$1<$D$1;WEEKDAY(A4;2)>5);1;0)))`,
    - to not add extra day for weekend dates, even if time difference suggests passing midnight.
  - third change:

    - and part: `+TIME(HOUR($F$1);MINUTE($F$1);SECOND($F$1))`
    - with: `+IF(WEEKDAY(A4;2)>5;TIME(HOUR($F$1);MINUTE($F$1);SECOND($F$1));TIME(23;59;59))`
    - to ignore fixed end time and "reset" end hour to near midnight (23:59:59) during weekends.

Note, that the above approaches solves "weekends" problem directly while [original blog post](http://onezeronull.com/2019/03/21/find-all-e-mails-sent-or-received-in-gmail-after-office-hours/)) uses separate column instead (see screenshot above) and thus formulas are a bit different.

Sources:

- [Find all e-mails sent or received in Gmail after office hours](http://onezeronull.com/2019/03/21/find-all-e-mails-sent-or-received-in-gmail-after-office-hours/)
- [How To Determine/Check If Date Is A Weekend In Excel?](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/07/15/excel-concatenate-strings-cells-columns/)
- [How To Convert Between Date And Unix Timestamp In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2473-excel-timestamp-to-date.html#a2)
- [CONCATENATE in Excel: combine text strings, cells and columns](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2473-excel-timestamp-to-date.html#a2)